# Java Mockito how to set new value for property

Tags: java, mockito

I have `Filter` mock object and pass it to testing method. It method change `Filter` meta property value. But in my test I get old value.

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:item[28140f6f5a] but was:item[3abf441213]
>       at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
>       ...

```
@Test
public void testMetaValue() throws Exception{
    when(f.getMetaData("last")).thenReturn("item3abf441213");

    WebUK at = new WebUK();
    at.setCollectingService(new TestCollectingServiceImpl());

    Set<Ad> ads = at.getNewAds(f);
    assertEquals(1, ads.size());
    assertEquals("item28140f6f5a",f.getMetaData("last"));
}
```

Object for test:

```
public Set<Ad> getNewAds(Filter filter) throws Exception {
        ...
        filter.setMetaData("last", ul.get(0).attr("id"));
        ...
}
```

Comment: You could use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn`, and have it check some kind of state before returning the appropriate value.

Comment: I think is working correctly, what you mocked was the method f.getMetadata("last"), then in the assertEquals is going to return "item3abf441213" and you compare with "item28140f6f5a" so will always fail, i did understand your example wrong?

Comment: My goal is to test or after getNewAds method filter MetaData("last") changed from "item3abf441213" to "item28140f6f5a".

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the set method was called with a verification:

```
verify(f).setMetaData("last", "item28140f6f5a");
```